# Como agregar dos valores lista a un diccionario y imprimir los valores de los dos values

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, txt

Estoy praticando con un arquivo txt para hacer un diccionario con el nombre de la receta como key y los ingredientes y preparación como values.
Y tengo que hacer que imprima sus ingredientes y preparacion.
Me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para hacer dos listas con los values y el resto del txt de cada una sea los valores de la lista.
Hasta ahora pude hacer este codigo
Mi idea que quando imprima alguna receta x el input sea sus ingredientes y metodos de preparacion, pero de la manera como Ingredientes: (*elementos aqui*)
Preparacion: (*elementos aqui*)

```
import pprint

with open("receta3.txt", encoding="utf-8") as Archivo:

quebralinha = True
Recetas = {}

for line in Archivo.readlines():
    line = line.strip()

    if quebralinha:

        if not "RECETA" in line:
            key = line
            Recetas[key] = []
            quebralinha = False
    else:

        if not "RECETA" in line:

            Recetas[key].append(line)

        else:
            quebralinha = True

for key in Recetas.keys():
  Recetas[key] = tuple(Recetas[key])

pprint.pprint(Recetas)
```

Aqui les dejo un fragmento del txt

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]RECETA 1
Pavo Flambeado al ron
INGREDIENTES
1 pavo de 7 kilos
1 ½ kilos de menudencias de pavo o pollo
3 cucharadas de mantequilla
1 atado de cebollinos
2 cebollas perla medianas
3 ramitas de tomillo
5 dientes de ajo
1 cucharadita de jengibre finamente picado
1 cucharada de páprika
1 vaso de ron
4 tazas de vino blanco
1 taza de caldo de gallina
½ taza de crema de leche
Sal y pimienta al gusto
PREPARACIÓN
1.Pique finamente una cebolla y la mitad de los cebollinos, triture 3 dientes de ajo, mezcle con la mantequilla reblandecida y adobe con todo esto el pavo por dentro y por fuera.
2.Inyecte el pavo con el vino, salpimiente y lleve a la refrigeradora para que se macere por 12 horas.
3.Coloque en una sartén la cebolla, el cebollino y el ajo restantes picados junto a la menudencia y dore lentamente.
4.Cuando las cebollas tomen color, añada el tomillo, el jengibre, la páprika, y salpimiente.
5.Añada el caldo de gallina y mantenga la cocción al menos una hora a fuego moderado con la sartén tapada, remueva constantemente y agregue líquido si es necesario.
6.Cuando esté cocido retire del fuego y cierna separando la menudencia y el jugo.
7.Rellene el pavo con la menudencia.
8.Regrese el líquido al fuego, añada la crema de leche y deje cocer por 5 minutos más, hasta obtener una salsa.
9.Suture la abertura del pavo para que se concentren los sabores del relleno.
10.Introduzca el pavo en una funda de hornear o en una pavera junto con el líquido en el que se maceró, selle y lleve a horno precalentado a temperatura media alta.
11.Cocine hasta que el indicador de cocción le indique que está listo o por aproximadamente 2 horas.
12.Retire el pavo del horno, retire la funda, bañe el pavo con el ron, préndale fuego para flambear y luego sirva acompañado de la salsa.

Comment: Si quieres guardar recetas, la solución propuesta es inadecuada. Si quieres practicar archivos y diccionarios, hay ejercicios más al punto. Después de probar muchas aplicaciones, finalmente anoto mis recetas en un cuaderno.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que estás pidiendo, la estructura de tu diccionario debería de verse así:

**Primera opción**: Por cada receta, tienes dentro otro diccionario donde tienes los ingredientes, y por otro lado la preparación.

`recetas = {'Nombre de la receta': {'Ingredientes': [], 'Preparacion': []}}`

**Segunda opción**: Por cada receta tienes una lista, donde la primera posición es una lista de los ingredientes, y la segunda posición es una lista con la preparación. En mi opinión esta puede parecer más sencilla si no se entiende la primera, pero la más recomendable sería la primera opción, ya que estás diciendo donde está cada cosa.
`recetas = {'Nombre de la receta': [[],[]]}`

Un ejemplo de la primera opción sería así:

```
recetas = {'Pavo Flambeado al ron': {'Ingredientes':['1 pavo de 7 kilos', '3 cucharadas de mantequilla'], 'Preparacion': ['1 Pique la cebolla', 'Inyecte el pavo con el vino']}}
```

Un ejemplo de la segunda opción se vería así:

```
recetas = {'Pavo Flambeado al ron': [['1 pavo de 7 kilos', '3 cucharadas de mantequilla'],  ['1 Pique la cebolla', 'Inyecte el pavo con el vino']]}
```

Y para imprimir recorres los nombres de cada receta (keys), y después vuelves a recorrer su valor (lista o diccionario) para ir viendo qué información hay en cada uno:

En el caso del diccionario:

```
# Recorremos todas las recetas
for i in recetas:
    # Mostramos el nombre de la receta
    print('Nombre de la receta:{}'.format(i))
    
    # Mostramos los ingredientes
    print('Ingredientes:')
    for j in recetas[i]['Ingredientes']:
        print(j)
    
    # Mostramos la preparacion
    print('Preparacion:')
    for j in recetas[i]['Preparacion']:
        print(j)
```

En el caso de la lista:

```
# Recorremos todas las recetas
for i in recetas:
    # Mostramos el nombre de la receta
    print('Nombre de la receta:{}'.format(i))
    
    # Mostramos los ingredientes
    print('Ingredientes:')
    for j in recetas[i][0]:
        print(j)
    
    # Mostramos la preparacion
    print('Preparacion:')
    for j in recetas[i][1]:
        print(j)
```